# Fire a workflow on item fetching

Tags: workflow, event-receivers, events

Is there a way to fire a workflow or event receiver for every item before its fetched from a list automatically? I need to update columns on every item every time a user enter the list or open a form. so its not an updating nor deleting nor creating event,its a fetching/getting.

what i need to do is to "link data" from an external source. its just for display purposes. Im planning on calling a stored procedure and updating the item with the current information.

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: What is the real objective? In other words, what is the task you need to solve? If you add more information maybee we can find out a third or fourth way to solve it :) Also, what version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Just added more info and added tag for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have some kind of unique ID that will be used in your list/library items/documents.

One approach that we are currently looking at:

Add a custom webpart to your "view form" and "edit form" pages (either in designer or using the ?toolpaneview=2 URL parameter).  On load, use a web services javascript call to reach into your data source and asynchronously display in a  somewhere on the page based on the value in that field.

You can apply updates to the fields from the "edit form" page for the user to save, but "view form" will only display

Comment: To add to this, if you only want to show it on view form I would go for JSLink on the field, view, or webpart, and in that file do the web services javascript call.